# saving an encrypted piece of text and then opening an decrypting it using a GUI application

Tags: c#, user-interface, encryption, savefiledialog, caesar-cipher

[image]
i have built an application where I can input a word or message into a textbox and click on my cipher button this will then generate a random key and encrypt that message I can then decipher that message by clicking my decipher button.MY problem is with my new features of a save and open button with this I want to save a message in its RAW enciphered format then be able to open it and decipher it as well as any other messages that have already been enciphered and previously saved. my problem is that this is not working I think it might be a problem with my save button because I also need to save the key as well as the message to decipher the message correctly this is just one of the things I have tried and I am quite stuck with this problem any help would be appreciated.Also the cipher I am using is the caesar cipher

the image is the GUI of the first stage of my working application with the message uptown funk being encryption. And obviously below is the code.

Edit-I have tried creating a tuple class to solve my problem but I have only used a class once never mind a tuple class and to put it bluntly after staring at it for a few hours I do not know how to get this to work some assistance would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.IO;

namespace login_form
{
public partial class Main : Form
{

    public string cipherText;
    public string originalText;
    public string DecipherText;
    public int key;

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static char cipher(char ch, int key)
    {
        if (!char.IsLetter(ch))
        {
            return ch;
        }

        char d = char.IsUpper(ch) ? 'A' : 'a';
        return (char)((((ch + key) - d) % 26) + d);
    }

    public static string Encipher(string input, int key)
    {
        string output = string.Empty;

        foreach (char ch in input)
            output += cipher(ch, key);

        return output;
    }

    public static string Decipher(string input, int key)
    {
        return Encipher(input, 26 - key);
    }

    private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnCipher_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Random rndNumber = new Random();
        tbKey.Text = rndNumber.Next(0, 26).ToString();
        originalText = tbWord.Text;
        try {
            key = Convert.ToInt32(tbKey.Text); 
        }
        catch {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input! Please Try Again"); 
        }

        cipherText = Encipher(originalText, key);

        tbOutput.Text = Convert.ToString(cipherText);
    }

    private void btnDecipher_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DecipherText = tbOutput.Text;
        string DecipherOutput = Decipher(cipherText, key);
        tbDecipheredOutput.Text = Convert.ToString(DecipherOutput);
    }

    private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var fileContent = string.Empty;
        var filePath = string.Empty;

        using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
            openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
            openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //Get the path of specified file
                filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

                //Read the contents of the file into a stream
                var fileStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile();

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                {
                    fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        tbOutput.Text = fileContent;

        MessageBox.Show("Path of File: " + filePath);//shows the path of the file 
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";//the format the file will be saved in 
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);//saves the folder to my documents 

        string Content = tbOutput.Text;//saves the contens of textbox output

        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                File.WriteAllText((saveFileDialog1.FileName), Content);
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File Was not Saved");
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

```
             using System;
             using System.Collections.Generic;
             using System.Linq;
             using System.Text;
             using System.Threading.Tasks;

          namespace login_form
          {
    class tuple
    {
        int key;
        string cipherText;

        static public void Main()
        {

            // Creating tuple with two elements 

            // Using Create method 

            var My_Tuple = Tuple.Create("lol", 23);

            Console.WriteLine("Element 1: " + My_Tuple.Item1);
            Console.WriteLine("Element 2: " + My_Tuple.Item2);

        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You need to save the key with the encrypted message.  You could set up a tuple class to hold the key as an integer and the message as a string.  Bundle the two together as a tuple for easier handling.  Add a decrypt method to the class.

Comment: I don't have to tell I suppose that saving the key with the ciphertext is rather insecure. That's not something you'd do normally. A very simple way would just to assume that the tuple starts with a decimal encoded key, followed by whitespace, and then the actual ciphertext. Then you have stringified everything.

Comment: @rossum I tried creating a tuple class because i have not used this class before a bit more information would be appreciated

Comment: By "tuple" I just mean a class with an integer (for the key) and a string for the cyphertext).  Add a two-parameter constructor and getters together with a `decrypt()` method.  You are only using a Caesar cypher, so you need not worry too much about security.  A Caesar cypher is easilt broken as there are only 26 possible keys to try.